# Trying to sed a file

Tags: linux

Current File consists of;

```
Computer1
Computer2
Computer3
[...]
```

Would like to change to;

```
Echo computer1;ssh computer1 date
Echo computer2;ssh computer2 date
[...]
```

---

Thanks so much for your help and apologies
I would like for it to look like
Echo computer1;net time -S computer1
Etc

Comment: Thanks to check how I edited your code blocks

Comment: Advice to newcomers: If an answer solves your problem, please accept it by clicking the large check mark (✓) next to it and optionally also up-vote it (up-voting requires at least 15 reputation points). If you found other answers helpful, please up-vote them. Accepting and up-voting helps future readers.

Answer (score 2):

Using [sed](/questions/tagged/sed):

```
$ sed -E 's/.*/Echo &;ssh & date/' file
Echo Computer1;ssh Computer1 date
Echo Computer2;ssh Computer2 date
Echo Computer3;ssh Computer3 date
```

or

```
$ sed 's/.*/Echo &;ssh & date/' file
Echo Computer1;ssh Computer1 date
Echo Computer2;ssh Computer2 date
Echo Computer3;ssh Computer3 date
```

- `.*` any character except newline from zero to the most possible occurences
- `&` the matched part